# How To Compare two .ico (icon) files in python?

Tags: python-3.x, image, python-2.7, compare, ico

Although i am new to python i just want to compare two .ico extension files. 
Anyone with the expertise can tell how can i do that? 
Is there any package or library readily available in python to do so ?

Thanks for reading the question. Your suggestions will be appreciated.

What I am currently doing is as follows but It is not giving me what i expect :

import cv2
import numpy as np

Original = cv2.imread("1.ico")
Edited = cv2.imread("chrome.ico")

diff = cv2.subtract(Original, Edited)

cv2.imwrite("diff.jpg", diff)

Comment: Do you want to compare them to see if there is a change, or you want actual differences?  And any reason why with python?  There may be tools that help you compare.

Comment: i just want to see if there is any change in it. looking forward to use it in a project with machine learning on which i am currently working.

Comment: In that case you use their SHA to see if anything has changed.

Comment: Okay. I'm on it.

Comment: Have posted sample code below.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to check if files have changes, you can use `hashlib` of python to get it.  The below code finds hash:

```
import hashlib

h = hashlib.md5()
with open('ico_file.ico', 'rb') as f:
    buffer = f.read()
    h.update(buffer)
    print(buffer) # May not be needed 

print(h.hexdigest())
```

Use the above code for the two files you want to compare and then match their output hash.  If it's the same, then files are very likely to be same.  If different, then they are definitely different.

Comment: Thanks Sid...That was very Helpful. Although it doesn't solved my problem completely..i got an idea about how to proceed.